# Automate replacement of missing data on a sequence of variables using mutate_all

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, dplyr

I am trying to automate a process to complete missing values on a sequence of variables using an ifelse statement and mutate_all function. The problem involves a dataframe with many variable names, for example, ax1, bx1, ...zx1, ax2, bx2, ...zx2, ax3, bx3, ...zx3. The following data give a small scenario:

```
df<-data.frame(
  "id"  = c(1:5),
  "ax1" = c(1, "NA", 8, "NA", 17),
  "bx1" = c(2, 7, "NA", 11, 12),
  "ax2" = c(2, 1, 8, 15, 17),
  "bx2" = c(2, 6, 4, 13, 11))
```

The process is to replace the missing values on the variables with the ending "x1" with their corresponding values on the variables with the ending "x2". That is, if ax1 is missing it is replaced by ax2 and any missingness on bx1 is replaced by bx2 and so on. Since there are many variables than the scenario presented here, I am looking for a way to automate this process. I have tried the following codes

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
mutate_all(vars(ends_with("x1", "x2")), function(x,y)
           ifelse(is.na(x), y, x)))
```

but it does not work. I greatly appreciate any help on this.
The expected output is

```
   id ax1 bx1 ax2 bx2
   1   1   2   2   2
   2   1   7   1   6
   3   8   4   8   4
   4  15  11  15  13
   5  17  12  17  11
```

Comment: What about missing values in `ax2` and `ax3`? Are they replaced? Or you want to replace missing values only from `ax1`?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks! missing values in ax2 and ax3  are not to be replaced. I want to replace missing values on variables that ends with x1, e.g. ax1, and  bx1.

Comment: Your missing are not really missing becuase you have quotes around the NA. You do not need quotes around NA or the column names e.g. "id" should just be id in the dataframe creation bit

Answer (score 0):

In base R, we can replace `NA` value in `x1` with corresponding `NA` values in `x2` using `Map`.

```
x1_cols <- grep('x1$', names(df))
x2_cols <- grep('x2$', names(df))

df[x1_cols] <- Map(function(x, y) {x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)];x}, 
                                   df[x1_cols], df[x2_cols])

df
#  id ax1 bx1 ax2 bx2
#1  1   1   2   2   2
#2  2   1   7   1   6
#3  3   8   4   8   4
#4  4  15  11  15  13
#5  5  17  12  17  11
```

---

We can use the same logic and use `purrr::map2`

```
df[x1_cols] <- purrr::map2(df[x1_cols], df[x2_cols], 
                      ~{.x[is.na(.x)] <- .y[is.na(.x)];.x})
```

**data**

Modified data a bit making sure that `NA` are actual `NA`s and not string "NA" which were actually making columns as factors.

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1:5),
               ax1=c(1,NA,8,NA,17),
               bx1=c(2,7,NA,11,12),
               ax2=c(2,1,8,15,17),
               bx2=c(2,6,4,13,11))
```

Comment: I think this is very specific to the columns/variables on which missing values are to be replaced. As I mentioned I am doing this on many variables, say ax1, bx1, cx1, dx1 and so. I thought mutate_all would make it less cumbersome?

Comment: @TRichard `mutate_all` would work on all columns. As you want to change only specific columns (`ends_with("x1")`) we can use `mutate_at` but it doesn't know about it's corresponding column i.e `ax1` has no idea about `ax2`. If we include both "x1" and "x2" columns in `mutate_at` it will change both the columns.